# Do any exotic smooth structures on $\mathbb R^n$ leave addition and negation smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space with the standard topology. We can equip $V$ with the "standard smooth structure," which includes as charts every linear isomorphism $\phi:V\to\mathbb R^n$. With this smooth structure, $V$ becomes a Lie group because $(x, y)\mapsto x+y$ and $x\mapsto -x$ are smooth. **Do any nonstandard/exotic smooth structures on $V$ also make these operations smooth?**

I'm wondering if perhaps the solution to Hilbert's fifth problem (or more basic principles) rule this out, but I'm too much of a novice in this area to understand what those results entail.

There are also some other posts regarding the relationship between exotic smooth structures and Lie groups [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31686/can-any-of-the-exotic-differentiable-structures-on-mathbb-r4-make-gl-mathb) [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509857/exotic-smooth-structure-and-homogeneous-spaces) [[3]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225910/exotic-smooth-structures-on-lie-groups?_gl=1*hkkipf*_ga*Mjg4MTg1NDU5LjE2MDMyOTg1NjM.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2Mzc5MDk4NS40NS4xLjE2NjM3OTE1ODkuMC4wLjA.), but again I'm too much of a novice to see whether those questions are directly relevant to this one.

Comment: An "exotic" smooth structure usually refers to one that is not *diffeomorphic* to the standard one, which is much stronger than just not being equal to it (e.g., you can take the standard one and transport it along some homeomorphism that is not smooth).  Exotic smooth structures in this sense only exist if $\dim V=4$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I forgot that $4$ is the only dimension allowing exotic structures. But does your first point imply that the answer to my question is "no"? It seems to say that a standard-smooth function on $\mathbb R^4$ *need not* be exotic-smooth (since the structures are not diffeomorphic). But couldn't $(•)+(•)$ and $–(•)$ still *happen* to be smooth in the exotic structure?

Comment: There is a smooth structure on $R^n$ that has the map $(x,y,z,\dots)\in R^n\mapsto (x^3,y^3,z^3,\dots)\in R^n$ as a chart, that is not the usual one, but that is not an exotic smooth structure. That's Eric's point.

Comment: If you put any smooth structure on $R^n$ that makes it a Lie group, then it will be a simply connected abelian Lie group and therefore the exponential map will be a diffeomorphism, so the smooth structure will give you a manifold diffeomorphic to the usual $R^n$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think this deserves to be an answer!